# Cover photo won't change on Google+

Tags: google-plus

Whenever I try to change my cover photo on Google+ it just says:

> There was an error changing your cover photo.     RETRY

As I recall I had the same problem about a month ago when I tried so it appears to be permanent. Do I need to contact Google themselves or might there be a workaround of some sort?

Error occurs regardless of which image I try to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that image you are trying to upload from your device or from Google Photos is not in a compatible format or size to use as a cover photo.

If you think you are using correct image, just give a try with another browser or clear the cache of you current browser and try to change cover photo again.

<sup>Here is a [non official site](https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/google-plus-cover-photo) which explain the size of cover and profile photo of Google+.</sup>

Comment: Tried both of those things. I tried multiple different images which work fine on most other social media sites, and also tried in another browser. I'll have a look over the site you linked to in a bit, though, just to check if there's anything I might have overlooked.

Comment: Every social media has their own dimension of photos. Did you tried to clear cache of your current browser? Download an image from [here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cover+photo+for+google+plus&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=606&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4i9fxzuHMAhXEQ48KHUUxBhkQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=cover+photo+for+google%2B) and try to make that your Google+ cover photo. Hope this will help you.

Comment: It's strange because it was refusing to allow me to set an image I'd previously set as a cover photo. But it's accepted one now, so I guess it probably was to do with what you said. Maybe they've been changing their formats or something. You'd thinking it'd at least tell me if it was to do with size or dimensions or whatever.